# How to make grub Command Line Default?

Tags: command-line, boot, grub2

I'd like to make grub by default load it's command line instead of automatically booting from it's list of options generated by `update-grub`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @richard How can I explain further? I want grub to by default to load it's command line instead of a set list of boot options.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted grub to terminate and I have described what I wanted grub to in in the question, simply load it's command line by default.

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with "simply load the command line by default".

Comment: @user133987 Don't pay attention to richard, he doesn't understand much. Your question was well phrased, but there may not be a good answer. One option for you might be to load grub as usual, but with no timeout.